# arrow pointer on nav links change onclick

Tags: html, css

i have managed to display Right Arrow pointer on my navigation list, and when i click on these navigation links they open a sub navigation list, what i want to happen is i want the arrow to change to a arrow pointing down when visiting, i have not been successfull, this is my code so far to get this to display a right arrow at the moment, any ideas on how to make it change onclick?

```
.sidebar-category li > a:before {
    color: #888;
    content: '► ';
}

.sidebar-category li > a:hover:before {
    color: #444;
    content: '► ';
}

.sidebar-category li > a:only-child:before {
    content: '';
}
```

Comment: Provide a jsFiddle link with your HTML code.

Comment: i would but my navigation is generated dynamically in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQ

```
$('.sidebar-category li').click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('clicked')
})
```

CSS

```
.sidebar-category li.clicked > a:before {content: '▼ ';}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know based on your description, but i would add following:

```
.sidebar-category li > a:focus:before {
    color: #444;
    content: '▼ ';
}
```

This might help... This is active yet only when you have clicked. Without jQuery this is a hard thing to solve.

I would use jQuery to add a class when user have clicked on the  called "open" and instead used following css:

```
.sidebar-category li > a.open:before {
    color: #444;
    content: '▼ ';
    }
```

The jQuery could look something like this:

```
$('.sidebar-category li > a').click(function() {
    this.toggleClass('open');
});
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: You can ofc change the class name to something more accurate.